# Named Constant 'BP' Replacing

Tags: core, core-config-data

At the top of `Mage.php` we have a few constants defined:

```
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('PS', PATH_SEPARATOR);
define('BP', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

I am coding something which will set values in the `core_config_data` such as values for `currency/options/allow` (e.g. `GBP,EUR,USD`). This is being populated by a YAML file parsed/decoded by `Zend_Config_Yaml`. Once decoded into an array, the value for `GBP,EUR,USD` is actually being outputted as so: `G/var/www,EUR,USD` where `/var/www` is obviously my `BP` path.

What would be the best way to overcome this?

YAML file is as so

```
    core_config:
      -
        path: general/locale/code
        value: en_GB
      -
        path: general/locale/timezone
        value: Europe/Paris
      -
        path: currency/options/allow
        value: GBP,EUR,USD
      -
        path: currency/options/default
        value: EUR
      -
        path: general/country/default
        value: FR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the option `ignore_constants` to true when you instantiate `Zend_Config_Yaml`.

> **ignore_constants**
>
> By default, `Zend_Config_Yaml` will replace constant names found in values with the defined constant value. You may pass a boolean `true` to this option to disable this functionality.

Source: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.config.adapters.yaml.html